# What causes the kill query in mysql

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I got a .net C# application which is using .net connector for mysql to connect and update data on the remote server. I notice at times there is a kill query by itself which cancels some of the queries. So how can I overcome this problem? I have checked that I don't at any place issue a `kill` in my code.

Below is a sample of the log file:

```
100717 15:26:03   979 Connect   root@60.50.6.130 on mpcms6
          979 Query SET autocommit=0
          979 Query SHOW VARIABLES
          979 Query SHOW COLLATION
          979 Query SET character_set_results=NULL
          979 Init DB   mpcms6
          979 Query SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
          979 Query BEGIN
          979 Query Update tblID Set tblID.lastValue = lastValue + 1 Where tblID.tableName='tblReceipt'
100717 15:26:33   980 Connect   root@60.50.6.130 on mpcms6
          980 Query SET autocommit=0
          980 Query SHOW VARIABLES
          980 Query SHOW COLLATION
100717 15:26:34   980 Query SET character_set_results=NULL
          980 Init DB   mpcms6
          980 Query KILL QUERY 979
          980 Quit  
100717 15:26:54   979 Query Insert into tblReceipt Set receiptID=2607, outletID=6, employeeID=86, customerName='Cash', customerPhone='', totalCostAmount=6.5, totalSellingAmount=40, totalProfitAmount=33.5, changeAmount=0, profit='y', receiptDate = '2010:07:17', receiptTime = '15:26:04'
          979 Query Update tblID Set tblID.lastValue = lastValue + 1 Where tblID.tableName='tblReceiptDetails'
100717 15:27:24   981 Connect   root@60.50.6.130 on mpcms6
          981 Query SET autocommit=0
          981 Query SHOW VARIABLES
          981 Query SHOW COLLATION
          981 Query SET character_set_results=NULL
          981 Init DB   mpcms6
          981 Query KILL QUERY 979
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a timeout. Both kills were ~30 seconds after the query started. Does your connector allow you to adjust the query timeout?

[Edit; answering comments]

I believe what you want is `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`, it's default is 30 seconds. See the [MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).

Comment: I am using .net connector from mysql itself. How the timeout comes from where actually? Is a behavior of mysql or .net connector?

Comment: @AIG yes I have read so what is the best timeout to be set in order to be save the query goes through successfully?

Comment: That would depend upon your queries; you'd have to tell me. :) For example, at my work, a query that ran for 30 seconds is unacceptable (too slow) and would be reworked.

Comment: @AIG the problem is my query are not big but the connection is quite slow as we are using a low end connectivity? So I think that cause it to be delay and plus at time few of machines are updating to this one machine.

Comment: I see. What is an 'unacceptable' time for you then? I'd use that as your benchmark and adjust from there.

Comment: If I say minute is it too much?

Comment: Depends upon your slow connection and your application.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Update you are executing appears to be simple (not hitting many rows)

I suspect that there is a lock on the table tblID and the client consequently runs into a timeout.

Comment: that could be a possible problem but not much update happens on tblID so what is the best mechanism to avoid this?